# $\frac {n}{θ}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}lnx_i=0$ How to get rid of that summation so I can get my θ estimator?

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

my question is in the title. Will copy it here as well:

$\ln L(θ) = n \ln θ + (θ − 1)\sum \ln x_i$

$\frac {dlnL}{dθ}=\frac {n}{θ}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}lnx_i$

$\frac {n}{θ}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}lnx_i=0$

How to get rid of that summation so I can get my $\hat θ$ estimator?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to get rid of the summation sign. Just treat that as one object. Note that now you want to solve for $\theta$ and make that as subject, and you are allowed to (must) in terms of the observed sample $x_i$

Comment: But I can't leave it like this, or can I? $\hat θ = - \frac {n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}lnx_i}$ And that minus sign, does that make sense? Btw thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{n}{\hat{\theta}}+\sum_{i=1} \ln x_i = 0$$

$$\frac{n}{\hat{\theta}}=-\sum_{i=1} \ln x_i $$

$$\frac{n}{-\sum_{i=1} \ln x_i }=\hat{\theta}$$

Comment: So that minus sign actually makes sense? And I can leave the summation as it is? Thank you Siong!

Comment: what types of value must $x_i$ take? if it is indeed between $0$ and $1$, then $\ln x_i <0$ and the negative sign will make $\hat{\theta}$ positive.

Comment: Oh, sorry! True! Thanks!